# Python + Boto3 for AWS S3: Error - Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"

Tags: python, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an input from the terminal being passed in `bucket-one`, which exists on Amazon Web Services’ S3, and when I attempt the following:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket = object(bucket)

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
```

I come across an error: `Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$”`. I even attempted to do `str(bucket_name)`, yet still getting the same error.

What could I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance and will be sure to vote up and accept answer

How I assign bucket_name:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Practice')
parser.add_argument('--bucket_name', nargs = 1, default = None)
args = parser.parse_args()
bucket_name = args.bucket_name
```

Comment: How are you assigning `bucket_name`?

Comment: Please show the code where `bucket_name` is set.

Comment: @jordanm Just did in the original post with EDIT

Comment: @Soviut Please take a look at the EDIT in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `nargs=1` from the `add_argument` call. From the `argparse` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html):

> Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

You want to pass a string to `s3.Bucket` containing only the bucket name, not a string representation of a one item list.